# Error While copying .abf file

Tags: ssis, ssas

When I try to copy an .abf file from one location to another location using file transfer task in SSIS package, I am getting

> The process cannot access the file .abf because it is being used by another process

Steps :

1. Once the cube is processed we restore the whole cube to another server ( From Server A to Server B) – Sucess
2. Copying .abf file from server A to some backup location – Above Error

Can anyone please just me what might causing this issue. Facing this issue everyday.

Comment: I would check with one of the methods described at http://superuser.com/questions/399659/how-can-i-identify-what-application-is-using-a-given-file which process is using the file first. The you can determine what to do when you have an idea who is the one using it.

Comment: I did this,but SSAS server only blocking it.But manually i am able to copy the file.

Comment: Maybe then you could try an "Execute Process Task" in SSIS that runs a DOS copy?